# java.sql.SQLException: Result set after last row

Tags: java, jdbc

I think I am having problem because of this line `rs.next();` in the `RequestDaoImpl` class mentioned below. Whenever I try to retrieve the value of `STATUS`, I keep on getting the following error:

`java.sql.SQLException: Result set after last row`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
  @Component
    public class GetStatus {

        @JmsListener(destination = "Queue1")
        public void processStatusMessage(String message) throws DaoException {

            System.out.println("Message Retrieved is:" +message);

            try {

            RequestDao requestDao = (RequestDao) context.getBean("requestDao");

            String receivedStatus = requestDao.getRequestStatus(message);

            System.out.println("Testing March 11");
            System.out.println(receivedStatus);



            }
            catch(Throwable th){
                th.printStackTrace();   

            }

         }

        private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");



    }
```

My RequestDao is :

```
public interface RequestDao {

    public String getRequestStatus(String msg)throws DaoException;

}
```

My RequestDaoImpl with the method implementation:

```
public class RequestDaoImpl implements RequestDao {

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) 
    {       
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);                                    
    }

    @Override
    public String getRequestStatus(String msg) throws DaoException {
        DataSource ds = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String requestStatus = null;

        //List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();

         try {

                ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
                conn = ds.getConnection();  

                //I am receiving message like this hence splitting it : 123456#Tan#development
                 String[] parts =   msg.split("#");
                 String requestID = parts[0].trim();
                 String userName =  parts[1].trim();
                 String applicationName = parts[2].trim();


                /*===========================================================================*/
                /*    Code to get the request status from Mytable          */ 
                /*===========================================================================*/
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT STATUS FROM Mytable WHERE request_user= ? and app_name =? and request_id=?");
                pstmt.setString(1,userName);
                pstmt.setString(2,applicationName);
                pstmt.setString(3, requestID);
                rs = pstmt.executeQuery();  
                rs.next();
                System.out.println("The status received is as follows:");

                requestStatus = rs.getString("STATUS");
                System.out.println(requestStatus);



        }
         catch(Throwable th) {
                throw new DaoException(th.getMessage(), th);
            }
            finally {
                if (rs != null) { try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (pstmt != null) { try { pstmt.close(); } catch(SQLException sqe) { sqe.printStackTrace(); }}
                if (conn != null) { try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException sqle) { sqle.printStackTrace(); }}

            }   



        return requestStatus;
    }
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;    
 }
```

Saw similar error post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418840/java-sql-resultset-exception) but their code is different than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That might happen because **no rows** were fetched.
`ResultSet#next` returns a `boolean` value which represents the presence or absence of a row.

What you'd need to apply is a condition to check that.
Being that you need a single row, an `if` is perfectly suitable.

```
if (rs.next()) {
   ...
   requestStatus = rs.getString("STATUS");
   ...
}
```

Note that your query can be optimized by applying a DBMS dependant keyword, such as `LIMIT` for `MySQL`

```
SELECT STATUS FROM Mytable WHERE request_user= ? and app_name =? and request_id=? LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hmm, I actually did this `if(rs.next()) {
     System.out.println(rs.getString("STATUS"));
    }else {
     System.out.println("Something wrong in the resultset");
    }` and it always end up printing `Something wrong in the resultset` . The SQL query on Oracle SQL developer is returning a row though.

Comment: @Tan that's not an error, it's just that no rows were retrieved. Check your SQL statement.

Comment: You are right, this SQL isn't returning any row. Thanks . I think I got confused with my other SQL query and thought that it's returning a row. The ID was different for that query.

Comment: @Tan and remember you can optimize your query by telling the DBMS to fetch only a single row. Like a wrote in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Good point. What would be an alternative for Oracle db? I believe `LIMIT` is only for MySQL.

Comment: @Tan Oracle 12c uses "fetch first row only". With 11g you'd need to use the implicit "rownum" column, such as "where rownum < 2"

Answer (score 0):

you should ask if resultset has values maybe with a while

`while(rs.next){
//your code here 
}`

that way you won't get in the error and just jump through return

Comment: I believe while loop won't work in my case since I am only getting a single row?

Comment: it will work if you have a single row it will enter one time do your job and will go out